# Why is a 60W RF relay used in a 100W amplifier?

Tags: power, rf, relay

The [IC9700 radio service manual](https://www.iz3mez.it/wp-content/library/appunti/Icom%20IC-9700%20Service%20Manual.pdf) (BOM page 35/5-14 and on schematic page 87/10-14) specifies the [Kemet EE2-3NUH-L RF relay](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_R7002_EC2_EE2.pdf) after the 100W PA, just before the antenna.

The Kemet relay [datasheet](https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/KEM_R7002_EC2_EE2.pdf) says max switching power is 60W (and 2A switching/carrying), but the radio is a 100W at 144MHz.

I doubt this was an oversight on the designer's part, or maybe it was, but clearly it operates fine.

**Under what conditions is it safe to run an RF relay above its specification?**

- At 50-ohms, 2A is 200W, is that the reason?

  - (There is additional matching after the relay before the antenna, so it may not be 50-ohm at that point.)
- Thus, can this [TE 5A surface-mount RF relay](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data%20Sheet%7F108-98001%7FZ.1%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_108-98001_Z.1.pdf%7F1462047-8) really handle 1250W at 50-ohms even though it too specifies 60W max current?

  - (It is not my plan to pump 1250W through an SMT relay, it seems like it would melt, but I would like to understand what is going on here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 60W rating is for each set of contacts. If you look at the radio schematic you will see that the two sets of contacts in the relay are wired in parallel, so 120W total.